# Http Error 405.0 - method not allowed iis 7.5 module staticfilemodule

Tags: iis-7.5, http-status-code-405

I have ran into an issue here that I can not seem to find a solutions for. I have a form that I am trying to deploy in IIS 7.5 and when I execute my script I get the following error...

```
Error Summary
HTTP Error 405.0 - Method Not Allowed
The page you are looking for cannot be displayed because an invalid method    
(HTTP verb) is being used.
Detailed Error Information
Module  StaticFileModule
Notification    ExecuteRequestHandler
Handler StaticFile
Error Code  0x80070001
Requested URL   http://localhost:80/Address.php
Physical Path   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Address.php
Logon Method    Anonymous
Logon User  Anonymous
```

I have tried everything under the sun. I have deleted the WebDavmodule....I have added the POST verb to the StaticFile Module....I have selected all verbs under the verbs tab. I have enabled the CGI.exe file...also I enabled the ISAPI module. I have read numerous articles on the issue and it seems a lot of people are having these issues and they didn't find a real fix for it. If there is any information someone could provide to help me get passed this I would be more than thankful. In addition, I checked the server log files. They are as follows...

```
#Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 7.5
#Version: 1.0
#Date: 2015-04-08 13:33:24
#Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken
2015-04-08 13:33:24 ::1 GET /validation_data.js 233 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/41.0.2272.118+Safari/537.36 200 0 0 171
2015-04-08 13:33:48 ::1 POST /Address.php - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/41.0.2272.118+Safari/537.36 405 0 1 3
#Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 7.5
#Version: 1.0
#Date: 2015-04-08 13:48:12
#Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken
2015-04-08 13:48:12 ::1 GET /indv/ - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/41.0.2272.118+Safari/537.36 403 14 0 17
2015-04-08 13:48:54 ::1 GET /Address.html - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/41.0.2272.118+Safari/537.36 304 0 0 1
2015-04-08 13:48:54 ::1 GET /validation_data.js 341 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/41.0.2272.118+Safari/537.36 200 0 0 25
2015-04-08 13:49:21 ::1 POST /Address.php - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/41.0.2272.118+Safari/537.36 405 0 1 2
2015-04-08 13:49:48 ::1 GET /validation_data.js 787 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/41.0.2272.118+Safari/537.36 200 0 0 33
2015-04-08 13:50:12 ::1 POST /Address.php - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/41.0.2272.118+Safari/537.36 405 0 1 3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I am not getting the error anymore. This is what I did. I installed PHP Manger for IIS 7.5 64bit. After that I installed Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2012 Update 4, which can be downloaded here http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=30679!